# Bat File to uninstall program

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am trying to create a batch file that will check to see if a program is installed on a machine. If it is installed, I want to uninstall it. If it is not installed, then do nothing.

Here is kind of what I was trying below:

```
IF EXIST wmic product where name="some program" 

call uninstall /nointeractive

ELSE \\ GOTO :eof

:eof

END && EXIT
```

Comment: didn't try, but something like `wmic product where name="some program" call uninstall`? See `wmic product call /?`

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before. Firstly `WMIC` does not `Call Uninstall` with arguments. Secondly, and more importantly, if `some program` was not a Windows Installer, installed product it will not exist under `Product`, *(Win32_Product)*.

Comment: Not even remotely close to the syntax for the IF command. I suggest you read the help file for the IF command to learn the syntax before you attempt to use it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your program name appears to be a protected secret, this would be my best guess:

```bat
(Echo Y|WMIC Product Where "Name='Program Name'" Call Uninstall)>Nul
```

*If the program isn't installed then nothing will happen!*